# What happened to Rin's Mana Compass?

Tags: fate-zero

In Fate/Zero, Rin is given a Mana Compass by her father which she uses in her search for Kotone. I've only seen up to episode 10 but I know she'll appear in a later episode where she will receive the Jewel Pendant which becomes the catalyst to summon Archer in the 5th war and saves Shirou's life.

However I don't remember her Mana Compass being mentioned in Fate/Stay Night, nor can i foresee a situation in Fate/Zero where it would be destroyed. Given how it works it seems to be quite a useful tool Rin could've employed in the 5th war.

So I am wondering, is it stated what happens to the compass, since it seems Rin treasures the Jewel Pendant she was given, since it came from her father, and I would assume she would treasure the compass as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it's never mentioned again (not even later in Fate/Zero), aside from a throwaway reference on [the Fake/states night webpage](http://www2.tba.t-com.ne.jp/taoru/resistance/fake/system.htm), which describes it (魔力針) as an item you could find in-game and which has Rin's name engraved on the back of it.

From an out-of-universe perspective, the obvious reason why we don't know what happened to it is that it was invented by Urobuchi for Fate/Zero, which was written after Fate/stay night, and it's not so important an object that its whereabouts in Fate/stay night would need to be explained.

From an in-universe perspective, I think the best explanation is that by the time of the Fifth War, Rin no longer needed the device - skilled mages can already sense magic to some extent. During the Fourth War, though, when she was just 5 or 6, she probably wasn't experienced enough to be able to detect mana all that effectively, and so the compass was somewhat useful to her back then.

By the way,

> Rin doesn't get the pendant during Fate/Zero. It's only at the beginning of F/SN (the day before she summons Archer) that she finds it with her father's effects. Rin does happen to show up at the end of Fate/Zero (for Tokiomi's funeral); that's when she receives the Azoth sword from Kirei.

Comment: So the Compass doesn't appear in Fate/strange fake which is what Fake/states night eventually became?

Comment: Right, it doesn't show up in Fate/strange fake itself (though that could change with the new novels coming out starting next month).

Answer (score 0):

Shirou could feel the presence of Medusa/Rider in the 5th Episode of Unlimited Blade Works.

I would say, if a third rate novice Magus could feel the presence of a Servant, a Genius like Rin wouldn't need her Mana-Compass anymore during the 5th Grail War.

Also, if I remember correctly. Command Seals vaguely "ping" Servants or strong Mysteries? Rin's Seals react in the Fuyuki Park in Episode 0 of UBW and she later feels the presence of Riders Blood Fort Andromeda, also during Episode 0.